# Pandas convert object column to str - column contains unicode, float etc

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, utf-8

I have pandas data frame where column type shows as `object` but when I try to convert to string,

`df['column'] = df['column'].astype('str')`

`UnicodeEncodeError` get thrown: 
`*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)`

My next approach was to handle the encoding part:
`df['column'] = filtered_df['column'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').strip())`

But that gives following error: 
`*** AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Whats the best approach to convert this column to string.

Sample of string in the column

```
Thank you :)
Thank You !!!
responsibilities/assigned job.
```

Comment: You can still use str.accessors with object columns. Try: `df['column'].str.encode('utf-8').str.decode('latin-1').astype(str)`

Comment: tried but gives me `*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: I'd like to see some of the data. Please see if you can reproduce this with some toy data.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in python 2.7 when trying to run a script that was originally intended for python 3. In python 2.7, the default `str` functionality is to encode to ASCII, which will apparently not work with your data. This can be replicated in a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['asdf', u'uh ™ oh', 123]})
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('str')
```

Results in:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Instead, you can specify unicode:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('unicode')
```

Verify that the number has been converted to a string:

```
df['column'][2]
```

This outputs `u'123'`, so it has been converted to a unicode string. The special character ™ has been properly preserved as well.

Comment: This answer saved by life. Thanks a ton