# Error related to decoding while combining pandas and shutil

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, shutil

I am trying to copy a bunch of directories with shutil.copytree and pandas (apply function). While checking the log I noticed that some files could not be copied due to the following error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:PATH. Even though the path name was valid. Upon further inspection it appeared the Í character was changed in \xb4, which explains why the file could not be found.

I have tried following the advice in this post:
[Pandas convert object column to str - column contains unicode, float etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177573/pandas-convert-object-column-to-str-column-contains-unicode-float-etc)
by trying to convert the column to unicode. However, this lead to the following error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil

def copy_files(row):
    try:
        shutil.copy(row['1'], row['2'])
        return 'DONE'
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

df = pd.DataFrame({'1':['Y:\project\Test\1\RAÍ.pdf'],'2': 
['Y:\project\Test\2\RAÍ.pdf']})

df['errors'] = df.apply(copy_files, axis=1)

print(df['errors'][0])
```

I expected that the string 'DONE' would be printed but instead I got the error message:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Y:\project\Test\x01\RAI\xcc\x81.pdf'

EDIT:

If use raw string literals like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({r'1':[r'Y:\project\Test\1'],
              '2':[r'Y:\project\Test\2']})

def copy_files(row):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(row['1'], row['2'])
        return 'DONE'
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

df['errors'] = df.apply(copy_files, axis=1)

print(df['errors'][0])
```

I still get the following result:

> [('Y:\project\Test\1\RAI\xb4i.pdf',
>   'Y:\project\Test\2\RAI\xb4i.pdf', "[Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'Y:\\project\\Test\\1\\RAI\xb4i.pdf'")]

Comment: wondering why you're seeing \xo1 in the output error and not "1"

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get those characters? It looks that your name contains a 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE'. The problem is that UNICODE (independently of the encoding) allows more than one representation. It can be (Normal Form C or Canonical Composition) U+00CD or `'\xcd'` or (Normal Form D or Canonical Decomposition) U+0049 followed with U+0301 or `'I\u0301'`. This NFD form read as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I followed with COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT.

It is impossible to distinguish those 2 forms on a printed or displayed characters, but unfortunately they are different strings for both Python and the filesystem...

How to fix: avoid non ascii characters in filenames. You now know why...

Workarounds:

1. Your source contains the NFD form. It is likely that the filesystem contains the NFC form, so you could try:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'1':['Y:\project\Test\1\RAI\xcd.pdf'],'2': 
   ['Y:\project\Test\2\RAI\xcd.pdf']})
   ```
2. The bulletproof way is to ask the filesystem what string actually is the filename:

   ```
   l = glob.glob('Y:\project\Test\1\RAI*.pdf')
   for name in l:
       print(name, [hex(ord(i)) for i in name])
   ```

   (notice the `*` and not a `?` because in NFD form a single glyph could correspond to more than one character) That would dump the unicode codepoints of all characters as known by the file system. Provided you later use the exact same representation thing should go fine.

---

Refences:

- [unicodedata — Unicode Database — Python 3.7.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html)
- [Unicode Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Canon_Compat_Equivalence)